# Simple Merge Sort bug in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion, mergesort

I'm doing a Merge Sort assignment in Python, but I keep have the error of `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Here's my code:

```
def merge_sort(list):
    left_num = len(list) // 2
    left_sorted = merge_sort(list[:left_num])
    right_sorted = merge_sort(list[left_num:])
    final_sort = merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)
    return final_sort

def merge(left_sorted, right_sorted):
    final_sort = []
    while left_sorted and right_sorted:
        if left_sorted[0] <= right_sorted[0]:
            final_sort.append(left_sorted[0])
            left_sorted.pop(0)
        else:
            final_sort.append(right_sorted[0])
            right_sorted.pop(0)
    final_sort = final_sort + left_sorted + right_sorted
    return final_sort

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list = [4, 2]
    print(merge_sort(list))
```

Can someone tell me why? To make the problem more usable to others, feel free to edit the question to make it make more sense. ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a recursive function, you should be careful about the base case, which decides when the recursion should come to an end.

In your case, the base case is missing. For example, if the list has only one element, then you don't have recursively sort it again. So, that is your base condition.

```
def merge_sort(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list
    ...
    ...
```

**Note:** The variable name `list` shadows the builtin function `list`. So better avoid using builtin names.

---

Since you are doing lot of `pop(0)`s, its worth noting that it is not efficient on lists. Quoting [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque),

> Though `list` objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for `pop(0)` and `insert(0, v)` operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation.

So, the better alternative would be to use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), instead of `list`, if you are popping a lot. The actual popping from a [`deque` is done with `popleft` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft).

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque([4, 2])
>>> d.popleft()
4
>>> d
deque([2])
```

Comment: Excuse me, for `deque`, how can I get the rest of the "list", after `popleft()`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an exit point in `merge_sort`. You need to do something like:

```
left_num = len(list) // 2
if left_num <= 1:
    return list
```

You always need to have a conditional exit in recursion function: `if COND then EXIT else RECURSION_CALL`.